# Exclude part of Regex Selection

Tags: regex

I try to catch somes "blocks" of my text file that are endend by a pattern with several "=" symbols.

I want to catch all these block without the final pattern but it's made with "=" that is use on some capture group of my block ... So when i select them, the pattern is always in the last match ...

Do you no a method for exclude it ?

A extract of my regex :

```
(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}) (.*)(Statut)([,:. aA-zZ0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ=><\n\r]*)\n
```

And block to analyse :

```
01-10-2021 16:02 utilisateur1Statut                   A réaliser =>
Ouverte
01-10-2021 16:03 utilisateur1Statut MyFile.txt      
01-10-2021 16:04 utilisateur1Statut               
utilisateur1 => utilisateur2
======================================================================
```

Warning : my block can be with one or more row with carriage return ...

Links to regex101 sample : https://regex101.com/r/hXu3QO/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of the pattern contains a character class `[,:. aA-zZ0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ=><\n\r]` that also matches `=` and newlines, so there is no rule to stop matching.

**Note** that `aA-zZ` is not the same as `[a-zA-Z]`

You can exclude the newlines from the character class, and repeat the matching starting with a newline and all lines that do not start with for example `===` or `\d{2}-`

You can make the rule as specific as you want of course.

```
(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}) (.*?)(Statut)\s*([,:. a-zA-Z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ=><]*(?:\n(?!===|\d{2}-)[,:. a-zA-Z0-9À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ=><]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1zg7t/1)

Comment: Thks a lot, what's the difference between aA-zZ and [a-zA-Z] (I found on google difference between [a-zA-Z] and [a-Z] but not this particularity ?

Comment: @Broshet See the explanation on `A-z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)

Z matches the character Z with index 9010 (5A16 or 1328) literally (case sensitive)

` See https://regex101.com/r/sAF8Nd/1 and the ascii table https://www.asciitable.com/